# How can I match and print out elements of strings within a list that do not match?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

## My problem

I have two lists 'predicted' and 'reference'. Each list contains strings, the first one being the predicted elements output by my model, and the latter being the gold-standard. I want to build an automatic error classifier, but can't figure out compare each character within each string within each list. I can compare wordwise (code included below) but I want to look character-by-character.

Below is the code for my word-wise comparer, along with the lists of data I'm working with NB, outside of this toy example, these lists are about 3000 items long.

```py
predicted = ['r * a k t\n', 'd * o u l\n', 'm * i s l\n', 'p * i . v @ p\n']
reference = ['r A k t\n', 'd * o u b\n, 'm * i s l\n, 'i * p . v @ t\n']

########### word-wise finder ##############
p = set(predicted)
r = set(reference)
errors = p - r

return(errors)
```

My code above returns me:

```py
'r * a k t\n', 'd * o u l\n', 'p * i . v @ p\n'
```

My dream would be to have a returned list that looks like this:

```py
['* a', 'l', 'p * i', 'p']
```

because I can then look at each element an classify the mistake it's made. 
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454570/how-can-i-subtract-two-strings-in-python

Comment: I don't see how that linked question resolves mine, I'm not looking to remove matching list elements, but rather to look at each element within a list and then return the elements which do not match, could you explain if I'm missing something?

Comment: If you convert each string into the list into a nested list, removing the matching elements will leave you with the non-matching elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you are looking for a character by character diff of each pair of words.

Assuming that you're looking for a minimal difference and the order of the characters matters, https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html provides a `SequenceMatcher` that implements the right algorithm.  Its output is a little confusing.

```
import difflib
print(difflib.SequenceMatcher(a='r * a k t\n', b='r A k t\n').get_opcodes()
# printed: [('equal', 0, 2, 0, 2), ('replace', 2, 5, 2, 3), ('equal', 5, 10, 3, 8)]
```

Which literally means that characters in `range(0, 2) == [0, 1]` in each are the same.  That is, `'r '` matches).

Then the characters in `range(2, 5) == [2, 3, 4]` in the first string have to be replaced by the characters in `range(2,3) == [2]` in the second string.  So `'* a'` gets replaced with `'A'`.

And then the characters in `range(5, 10) == [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` in the first string match the characters in `range(3, 8) == [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` in the second string.  In other words `' k t\n'` matches.

For the format that you seem to be looking for (stuff in the first list not in the second), it suffices to look for only opcodes `replace` and `delete`.  The other two opcodes are `equal` and `insert`.